# show more/less with FAQ with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a newbie with html and i need your support. Please look at my code:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/ghLoau6r/1/

Now I want to make a list of FAQs as table. The requirements are:

- when we click to any link button (here we have 2 link buttons as 2 rows of the table), the background must be changed (not pink anymore, but another color)
- when we click to any link button, the triangle at the beginning of the row also changes to another form (i created already but my code does not run)
- when we click "show info 2", the corresponding "content 2" should be shown, instead of "content 1" now.

please help me, thank you guys very much !

Comment: `<script style='text/css'>` -- I saw this as the first line of your code. I don't think you have any idea what you're doing, making it very difficult to help...

Comment: not accepting previous good answers, and not casting a single upvote, don't help either.

Comment: You better try out these examples here to get started: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

Comment: thank you guys for telling the truth. I agree that i have very little knowledge about html. I also dont want to ask before i really give up. But this case i am in emergency, therefore i need to ask. After this i will learn html carefully. 

I have corrected some points of my code, so problem with ID is solved but it looks still stupid. Could you guys please at least point me out how to fix next problems with background and triangle form ?


https://fiddle.jshell.net/ghLoau6r/5/

Answer (score 1):

So, not to be rude but there is *so* many things that need to be fixed here, that I don't have time to share them all with you.  I'd strongly recommend picking up a book (HeadFirst HTML & CSS isn't bad, there are plenty others) and getting a solid understanding before continuing the work.

That said, the core problems to your specific question are that first, ID's should be unique (you have two elements with the ID of 'content1').  Second, your second link is looking for content1 still, even though you want content2.  A quick fix would be to update the ID of the second content area ,and then update the anchor onclick handler to look for the correct ID.

That said, this is pretty far from an ideal or scalable solution, so please read up.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, I think it will be hard to help without completely writing it for you. But I'd like to at least point out that you should move your JavaScript from inline/in the HTML into a separate JS file.

In your JS Fiddle, take this:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('content1').style.display=(document.getElementById('content1').style.display=='none')?'block':'none'"
```

And put it in the "JavaScript" section of JS Fiddle, inside of a `$(document).ready()` function. Use `jQuery` to register the onclick event to the behavior you want. Can include jQuery in your fiddle by using a jQuery URI such as `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js`

Godpseeed

Comment: You know, I really thought about pointing him at jQuery also, but I figured he's got enough to learn without adding more. :P  And I have a soft spot in my heart for folks willing to rock Vanilla, as I got started in JS before any of the good frameworks were out.

Comment: @Paul - I hear that. But even when I didn't fully understand what jQuery was doing for me, as a newbie trying to get stuff working, I really appreciated the simplicity and ease-of-use jQuery brought